# How can I find the file which is executed when a terminal command is entered?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Is there any way that I can find the location of the file that is run when I execute a command in the terminal? I know that commands such as `ls` and `cd` are in `/bin`, but is there a command that I can run on a command to see where its file is located?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for `which`

**Example**

```
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls

$ which pwd
/usr/bin/pwd
```

From man page

```
NAME
       which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.
DESCRIPTION
       Which takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints
       to stdout the full path of the executables that would have been exe‐
       cuted when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt. It does
       this by searching for an executable or script in the directories listed
       in the environment variable PATH using the same algorithm as bash(1).
```

---

**whereis**

you may also want to look at `whereis`

**Example**

```
$ whereis ls
ls: /usr/bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1p.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz


NAME
       whereis  -  locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a com‐
       mand
```

**type**

```
   type — write a description of command type
```

**Example**

```
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
```

Comment: Might want to mention the `type` built-in which does a similar task.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have added some more details to the answer. Hope this is fine now

Comment: Better but `type` does non-built-ins too and also does built-ins, aliases and functions (which the others don't).